# Call function using JQuery when radio button client side check chaged

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radio-button

I have radio buttons that are `AutoPostBack="true"` and want to call function by JQuery when client side check change event before postback like `OnClientClick` in asp button.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoptiontxt" runat="server" Text="Text Box"  AutoPostBack="true"
                GroupName="Qypye" oncheckedchanged="rdoptiontxt_CheckedChanged"/>

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoptiontxtArea" runat="server" Text="Text Area"  AutoPostBack="true"
                GroupName="Qypye" oncheckedchanged="rdoptiontxtArea_CheckedChanged"/>
```

Comment: You should have included this in your previous post why create a new one ? Well, any success if included `onclick` on the Radiobutton markup ?

Comment: using `onclick` will stops Autopostback even returned `true`

Comment: You can use  `__doPostback(this," ")` event instead of returning true. If condition fails no postback if true perform a `__doPostback()`

Comment: @Suprabhat `__doPostBack()` working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `AutoPostBack` attribute and call the postback using `__doPostBack()` in JavaScript.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoptiontxt" runat="server" Text="Text Box"  
            GroupName="Qypye" oncheckedchanged="rdoptiontxt_CheckedChanged" onclick="persistingTextBox(); "/>

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoptiontxtArea" runat="server" Text="Text Area"  
            GroupName="Qypye" oncheckedchanged="rdoptiontxtArea_CheckedChanged" onclick="persistingTextBox(); "/>
```

JavaScript

```
function persistingTextBox() {
        //Do whatever you want
        __doPostBack();
}
```